# Paperless-ngx redo OCR for documents

Tags: ocr, paperless

I'm trying to redo the OCR for my documents on Paperless-ngx, because some obvious text on the PDF's are missing or not indexed automatically. What should I do to redo OCR for specific documents ?

I'm using the docker installation so I have the following containers running:

```
paperless-webserver-1
paperless-broker-1
paperless-db-1
paperless-gotenberg-1
paperless-tika-1
```

I have found the [following discussing](https://github.com/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx/discussions/405) on the GitHub page but it doesn't tell how to actually do it, just "implemented".

There are also mentions of `PAPERLESS_OCR_MODE=<mode>` in their [documentation](https://docs.paperless-ngx.com/configuration/).
However again, no example and I couldn't find where to apply the setting.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a force OCR by running this command:

```
docker exec -d  -e "PAPERLESS_OCR_MODE=force" paperless-webserver-1 document_archiver --overwrite --document [HERE_COMES_THE_DOCUMENT_ID]
```